# Как временно "приглушить" monit на период развертывания сервиса через ansible?

Tags: linux, развертывание, ansible, monit

Есть сервер на linux, на нем работает некий сервис *myservice*, за сервисом наблюдает [*monit*](https://mmonit.com/monit/). Сообщает на почту обо всех изменениях и при необходимости перезагружает сервис.

Есть ansible playbook, который переустанавливает сервис, конфигурирует и перезапускает. И monit тоже конфигурирует и перезапускает при необходимости. Работает это отлично, но плохо то, что при этом monit шлет пачку писем:

- service instance пропал
- service instance появился
- service instance сменил PID
- monit перезагрузился

Можно в роли давать monit задачу приостанавливать мониторинг, но об этой задаче он тоже сообщает. Дважды.

```
- name: monit не наблюдает за myservice
  shell: monit unmonitor myservice

- name: monit наблюдает за myservice
  shell: monit monitor myservice
```

Можно перезапускать сервис из самого monit'a. Тогда письма приходят с менее угрожающими заголовками, вроде `Action done myservice`. Но всё равно одно или два письма + одно про релоад монита.

```
- name: Перезапуск myservice через monit
  shell: monit restart myservice
```

Я беспокоюсь о том, что это всё сработает как у мальчика, который кричал «Волки!». Все привыкнут, что с почты постоянно валится куча писем и что это нормальный процесс, волноваться не о чем. Поэтому хочу, чтобы штатные работы не приводили ни к каким тревогам вообще.

Можно ли это как-то реализовать на этом стеке технологий? Или я категорически неправ в своих опасениях?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Решение

### monit

config: `/etc/monit/monitrc`

```
 set alert {{mail_recipient}}  but not on { action, instance }
```

#### ansible:

Во всех командах параметр `-I` нужен, почему — смотри ниже.

В начале установки через monit останавливаем сервис, это считается `action`

```
- name: Остановка myservice через monit
  shell: monit -I stop myservice
```

Потом производим всю необходимую установку и настройку.

Убеждаемся, что сам monit запущен. 
Перезагружаем конфиги через сам monit, это событие типа `instance`

```
- name: Убедиться, что monit запущен
  service: name=monit state=started

- name: Перезагрузка конфигов monit
  shell: monit -I reload
```

Потом перезагружаем сервис, это считается `action`

```
- name: Перезапуск myservice через monit
  shell: monit -I restart myservice
```

---

## Конфигурация monit

Получать только определенные события

```
set alert foo@bar only on { timeout, nonexist }
```

Получать все события кроме некоторых:

```
set alert foo@bar but not on { instance }
```

Подробнее про фильтрацию событий в monit:

https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-event-filter

## Оставшиеся проблемы

1. [monit "забывает" команды, отданные после перезагрузки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471373/181472) — решено.

   Разобрано в отдельном вопросе, здесь я просто добавляю `-I` к командам.
2. C такой конфигурацией monit перестает сообщать об изменениях собственного instance не только на период развертывания, а вообще. То есть, если он был перезагружен вручную, либо если упал а потом был поднят при развертывании — то сообщения не будет.

   Можно оставить только такой конфиг:

   ```
   set alert {{mail_recipient}}  but not on { action }
   ```

   Но тогда при развертывании все равно будет одно сообщение на почту про `sudo monit reload`. Безуспешно пробовал такую схему, она не работает.

   - name: monit - приостановить мониторинг
     shell: monit unmonitor all
   - name: monit - перезагрузка конфигов
     shell: monit reload
   - name: monit - возобновить мониторинг
     shell: monit monitor all