# monit "забывает" команды, отданные после перезагрузки

Tags: ansible, monit

Обнаружил проблему при деплое через ansible playbook, но воспроизвел и запуская команды вручную через SSH.

В ansible стоят одна за другой две задачи. Перезагрузка конфигов monit, потом от имени monit включение сервиса.

```
- name: monit - перезагрузка конфигов
  shell: monit reload

- name: Запуск myservice через monit
  shell: monit start myservice
```

При этом иногда сервис не включается. Наблюдения показали, что это происходит с большей вероятностью на более слабой машине; других зависимостей пока не выявил.

Смотрю в `/var/log/monit.log` и вижу там следующее:

Только `monit reload`:

```
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:35] info     : Reinitializing monit daemon
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:35] info     : Awakened by the SIGHUP signal
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:35] info     : Reinitializing monit - Control file '/etc/monit/monitrc'
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:35] info     : Shutting down monit HTTP server
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:36] info     : monit HTTP server stopped
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:36] info     : Starting monit HTTP server at [localhost:2812]
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:36] info     : monit HTTP server started
[NOVT Dec  2 19:33:36] info     : 'myhost' Monit reloaded
```

Только `monit myservice restart`:

```
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : 'myservice' start on user request
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : monit daemon with PID 29544 awakened
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : 'myservice' start: /etc/init.d/myservice
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : 'myservice' start action done
```

Обе команды: `monit reload; monit myservice restart`. Отметил числами, к какой команде относится каждая строка лога.

```
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : Reinitializing monit daemon
2 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : Awakened by the SIGHUP signal
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : Reinitializing monit - Control file '/etc/monit/monitrc'
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : Shutting down monit HTTP server
2 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : 'myservice' start on user request
2 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : monit daemon with PID 29544 awakened
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : monit HTTP server stopped
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : Starting monit HTTP server at [localhost:2812]
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : monit HTTP server started
1 [NOVT Dec  2 18:57:56] info     : 'myhost' Monit reloaded
```

Эти строки лога отсутствуют:

```
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : 'myservice' start: /etc/init.d/myservice
[NOVT Dec  2 18:58:26] info     : 'myservice' start action done
```

Почему-то вторая команда выполняется не полностью. Пока что решил это с помощью костыля, время найдено опытным путем.

```
sudo monit reload; sleep 5s; sudo monit restart myservice
```

То же самое в ansible

```
- name: monit - перезагрузка конфигов
  shell: monit reload

- name: Подождать 5s
  shell: sleep 5s

- name: Запуск myservice через monit
  shell: monit start myservice
```

Остается два вопроса:

1. Что происходит, почему monit "забывает" вторую команду?
2. Как сделать то же самое нормально, без костылей с ожиданием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По логам можно заметить, что monit действительно выполняет команды асинхронно, как уже отметил alexander barakin.

monit устроен таким образом:

- Команда `monit` без параметров запускает monit в режиме демона.
- Команда `monit` с параметрами, например `monit reload`, отдает демону задачу, которую он выполняет асинхронно. При этом команда завершается (returns) сразу, а задача — нет.

Связь между загрузчиком команд и демоном через `localhost:2812`, причем нужно в конфигах отдельно разрешить соединение на этот адрес и порт. В данном случае HTTP-сервер успевает принять задачу `monit start myservice`, после чего задача `monit reload` успешно закрывает HTTP-сервер и открывает новый. Задача теряется.

Против этой особенности помогает ключ `-I`, который заставляет monit выполнять команды синхронно. При этом отдаваемые команды завершаются только после завершения задачи демона. Чтобы иметь возможность отслеживать результаты, можно добавить `-v`:

```
- name: monit - перезагрузка конфигов
  shell: monit -I -v reload

- name: Запуск myservice через monit
  shell: monit -I -v start myservice
```

Answer (score 2):

*monit*, насколько я знаю, выполняет вызовы асинхронно.

вот [здесь пишут](https://github.com/cargomedia/puppet-packages/issues/788), что, начиная с версии *5.9*, справились с [описанной проблемой](http://www.cargomedia.ch/2014/04/25/reliably-reloading-monit.html), когда при вызове `monit reload; monit unmonitor apache2` второе обращение (`unmonitor apache2`) не выполнялось из-за того, что *monit* в это время перезагружался.

правда, не совсем понятно, относится ли это к команде *monit reload*.

Comment: В точности так. Вчера вечером разобрался, написал более подробный отчет и решение.